# Rotating Multiple URLs within an Iframe Window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, rotator

I have 30 different urls that I want to feed into an iframe src attribute that I would also like to rotate as i click next button,reload,previous buttons between all the 30 urls within the iframe.
how to do this using javascript/best approach for a blog?
thanks.

Comment: store the urls in array and traverse array elements before setting as iframe src

Comment: Please provide [mcve] of what you have attempted so far.